# How to generate createdAt and updatedAt timestamps/datetime using CodeIgniter DB Forge?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3, data-migration

I would like to have 2 timestamp/datetime fields, **createdAt** which only contains the time when the record was created but doesn't update constantly if there are updates on the record and **updatedAt** which generates during the time when the record was created and everytime the record gets updated. It's also said that a record should only contain one timestamp field at least for MySQL?

Here is my migration code:

```
$this->dbforge->add_field(array(
    'id' => array(
        'type' => 'INT',
        'constraint' => 5,
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'auto_increment' => TRUE
    ),
    'name' => array(
        'type' => 'VARCHAR',
        'constraint' => '50',
    ),
    'createdAt TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
));
```

How is this done using CodeIgniter DB Forge? Any answers are well appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it, here is my solution:

```
$this->dbforge->add_field(array(
    'id' => array(
        'type' => 'INT',
        'constraint' => 5,
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'auto_increment' => TRUE
    ),
    'name' => array(
        'type' => 'VARCHAR',
        'constraint' => '50',
    ),
    'createdAt timestamp default now()',
    'updatedAt timestamp default now() on update now()'
));
```